# Placement of a decoupling capacitor

Tags: capacitor, pcb, decoupling-capacitor

I am using the CD4046, and trying to put a decoupling capacitor on it. However, the power pin is on the literal opposite side of the power pin, like so.

[image]

As you can see, I have a decoupling capacitor, that is meant to connect the ground pin (VSS, pin 8) with the power pin (VDD, pin 16). I was wondering whether I could do this.

[image]

Per my understanding, decoupling capacitors work by isolating parts of the circuit from noise of power. So far, I think this would work because the capacitors would still charge and discharge under power disruptions.

Please let me know if more info is needed, or if the answer is glaringly obvious.

Edit: I am using a 4-layer PCB with a designated ground plane.

Comment: Note that a 4046 switches very slowly, so a little bit of a loop here isn't a big deal. Just put the cap near pin 16 and connect it to the ground plane there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting a capacitor with both ends connected to ground does nothing, the capacitor is shorted out.

Is this a two or a four layer board?  For two layer, a common thing to do is to put the capacitor on the backside halfway between the pins or to put it along the top next to the VDD and run a trace under the chip (all on one side).  For four layer with a ground plane under the chip, just put it next to the VDD pin with a via to the ground plane.  Since this chip only has one power pin, and is an ancient through-hole part, it probably is ok with any of these options and does not require extremely low impedance decoupling.

Comment: I'm guessing that means my two-capacitor design isn't going to cut it.



As for boards, it will be a 4 layer board, with one GND layer and two power layers (one at 15V and the other at 7.5). The power layers were implemented via a simple voltage divider in the breadboard phase, in case this info helps.

Comment: @HFOrangefish I would probably put the cap on the same side along the top with a via to ground just for simplicity and since it doesn't really matter which of the many good options you pick.

Comment: @HFOrangefish I recommend using at least two vias to connect the cap to the ground plane.

Comment: @HFOrangefish Powering a plane from a voltage divider sounds like a bad idea, but that's probably something you should put into its own question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention your stackup here, but it will affect your decision.  If you have fairly solid power and ground planes under this chip, I'd place the cap on the other side of the board with its vias as close to each other as possible leading to the planes.  If you're using one-sided assembly, choose someplace to minimize the total distance.

If you have a ground plane but no power plane, position the cap near the Vcc pin, as the ground path will be lower impedance.  If you have no ground plane, keep the leads as short and wide as possible to minimize the inductance.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a ground plane, and the decoupling capacitor should be located as close to the VCC pin as possible. Its other end should connect directly to the ground plane with a very short stub trace. The GND pin of the chip should connect directly to the ground plane.

If a ground plane is not possible eg. in a 2-layer board, then the decoupling capacitor should be surface mount and placed diagonally under the chip, directly on a line between the vias that are placed next to the pads of the power pins of the chip. That is ideal. The chip’s GND pin is then a reference point for a star ground. R1 and R2 should then be connected to that point, and not to some other point on the GND circuit.

For best performance of CD4046 on a 2-layer board, a local ground plane is desirable. For through hole construction, it usually would be on the top layer. For SMT, the bottom layer would be preferable if most passives are on the top layer. Sometimes a layout has chips and the ground plane on top, and passives on the bottom. This is also acceptable for CD4046, since it’s a rather low-frequency device where via parasitics don’t matter.